# Getting List() From DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public JsonResult SearchApplicantList(string SSession, string ApStatus, string StudyLevel, string SLPrograms)
{
    ab db = new ab();

    var SearchList = db.Students
                       .Where(x => x.SemesterSessioin == SSession  
                                   && x.OverAllStatus == ApStatus 
                                   && x.StudyLvl == StudyLevel 
                                   && x.ProgPref1 == SLPrograms 
                                   && x.ProgPref2 == SLPrograms 
                                   && x.ProgPref3 == SLPrograms 
                                   && x.progPref4 == SLPrograms).ToList();

    return Json(SearchList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I want to get a list on the basis of parameters, but few cases the many parameters can be null, null means all.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking for an `OR` search rather than an `AND` search (which is far more common)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public JsonResult SearchApplicantList(string SSession, string ApStatus, string StudyLevel, string SLPrograms)
{
ab db = new ab();

var SearchList = db.Students;
 SearchList = SearchList.Where(x => (x.SemesterSessioin == SSession || SSession ==null || SSession =="")
                               && (x.OverAllStatus == ApStatus || ApStatus ==null || ApStatus =="")
                               && (x.StudyLvl == StudyLevel || StudyLevel ==null || StudyLevel =="")
                               && (x.ProgPref1 == SLPrograms || SLPrograms ==null || SLPrograms =="")
                               && (x.ProgPref2 == SLPrograms || SLPrograms ==null || SLPrograms =="")
                               && (x.ProgPref3 == SLPrograms || SLPrograms ==null || SLPrograms =="")
                               && (x.progPref4 == SLPrograms|| SLPrograms == null|| SLPrograms == "").ToList();

return Json(SearchList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: And that is how one creates convoluted SQL. Also, this approach is quite limited to simple scenarios like this, whily dynamically constructing the SQL allows more complex scenarios where i.e. parameters create subqueries.

Comment: @TomTom SQL query like  select * from Students x where (x.SemesterSessioin = 'SSession' or 'SSession' =null) and (x.OverAllStatus = 'ApStatus' or 'ApStatus' =null) ...etc

Comment: if parameter null sql  ignore it because null = null means select all

Comment: Yeah. Well, seems you did not try to understand my comment. In my line of work, that is firing level code - leads to parameter creep and possibly slow queries. YOu do know SQL parameter creep problems with this semantic, right?

Comment: @TomTom SQL Accept " "? like select all

Comment: @ZiaURRahman do you mean say "" like null

Comment: @erdiyılmaz yes

Comment: I edit my answer for ""

Answer (score 1):

Programming. Step by step.

Let me explain:

There is no need to have only one line for the query.

```
var searchQuery = db.Students (possibly with .Where that is constant).

if (ApStatus != null) {
  searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(x => x.OverAllStatus = ApStatus
}
```

Btw., plenty of spelling. It is App (not Ap) and Overall not OverAll - it is ONE word as per dictionary.

Anyhow, you can repeat adding where conditions as often as you want, then at the end materialize.

All where conditions are ANDed together.

This is one thing most people overlook - LINQ allows a TON of programming and manipulation of the query tree.

Comment: ok how i collect all records,     if (ApStatus != null) {data list=10records}       if (SSession!= null) {list =20 records}                            how i collect these two records?for display to table?

Comment: with .Take(N)  if (ApStatus != null) {data list = searchList.Take(10)} if (SSession!= null) { list = searchList.Take(20)}

Comment: i mean if i found 10 records in  (ApStatus != null)  and 20 records found in if (SSession!= null)            total records is 30? ok, how i plus these records 20+10 list for display in table

Comment: Ah, not sure what you mean. In the approach I showed there still only is ONE list materialized. I never tell to get the results of ApStatus != null, I tell to add the condition to the query and then the next condition TO THE SAME QUERY. You still only make ToLists once.

Comment: with list1.addRange(list2) you can add elements from the second list if they are the same T object lists, 10+20   https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-5.0

Comment: Point is there should not be a second list as per the query and my answer. addRange would not solve anything given how the problem is described.

Comment: i agree with TomTom, it seams another question , the first query don't result in two lists ...

Comment: I have a feeling OP wants to `or` the filters and not `and` them which is what this does.

Comment: Nah, the OR conditions are on the ProfRef and as they all depend on ONE parameter, my answer stands - you can then have the multiple condidions in ONE where. The OP seems not to really know any logic programming.

Comment: I'm not complaining about your answer, just thinking that OP is having trouble expressing themselves in a second language.

Answer (score 0):

Apply filter by parameter/s which can not be null, for instance SSession and StudyLevel are those parameters which can not be null. So apply filter by them first

```
var SearchList = db.Students.Where(x => x.SemesterSessioin == SSession && x.StudyLvl == StudyLevel).ToList();
```

Then check rest of parameters one by one, for SLPrograms will be like:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SLPrograms))
{
  SearchList = SearchList.Where(Apply Filter By SLPrograms).ToList();
}
```

And then for rest of Parameters. Remember, use if and if to check each parameters. Like

```
if(Param1)
{
   //Code
}
if(Param2)
{
   //Code
}
```

Comment: ok i got it , but am facing problem is how i plus these records for display                              
if(Param1)
{
   //found 10 records
   
}
if(Param2)
{
   //20 records
}
if(Param3)
{
   //5 records
}
how i collect thses 35 records for display?

Comment: You will be filtering result as you are applying filter. For example, assume you get 100 rows in table and when you apply first filter with constant parameter, it narrows down to 70 record, and then as you applying more filter it will narrow down to 35 records as your query. You don't need to add records in list. Applying filter will remove unmatched data from list by itself.